# Mirage asking for modelid

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

So I am trying to setup mirage to use faker and I have done that but I am getting the following error:

```
assert.js:35 Mirage: The route handler for /services/1 is trying to access the :serviceId model, but that model doesn't exist. Create it using 'ember g mirage-model :service-id'.
```

Here is my mirage/config

```
export default function() {
  this.get('/services/categories');
  this.get('/services/:service_id');
}
```

Let me know if you need to see more data

Comment: Can you post the route handler for the services/:service_id route?

Answer (score 1):

Mirage's default to config would be to make things like this:

```
export default function() {
  this.get('/services/categories');
  this.get('/services/:id');
}
```

Does that fix your issue?